# Identifying locations of distinct sublists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `J1` containing many sublists. I am identifying all the distinct sublists and the locations (first and last) at which they occur. I present the current and expected output.

```
J1 = [[0, 3, 7, 9, 10], [0, 3, 7, 9, 10], [0, 3, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 0, 9, 10]]

distinct_sublists = []
sublist_indices = {} 
for i, sublist in enumerate(J1):
 if sublist not in distinct_sublists:
     distinct_sublists.append(sublist)
     sublist_indices[tuple(sublist)] = [i, i]
else:
    sublist_indices[tuple(sublist)][1] = i

num_distinct_sublists = len(distinct_sublists)

first_last_locations = [[indices[0], indices[1]] for indices in sublist_indices.values()]

print("Number of distinct sublists in J1:", num_distinct_sublists)
print("First and last locations of distinct sublists in J1:", first_last_locations)
print("Distinct sublists", distinct_sublists)
```

The current output is

```
Number of distinct sublists in J1: 3
First and last locations of distinct sublists in J1: [[0, 0], [3, 3], [5, 5]]
Distinct sublists [[0, 3, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 0, 9, 10]]
```

The expected output is

```
Number of distinct sublists in J1: 3
First and last locations of distinct sublists in J1: [[0, 2], [3, 4], [5, 5]]
Distinct sublists [[0, 3, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 0, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: The `else` should line up with the `if`, not with the `for`. If you use consistent indentation then it's easier to spot issues like this when you review your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks perfect except for the indentation, just indent the "else" statement:

```py
for i, sublist in enumerate(J1):
    if sublist not in distinct_sublists:
        distinct_sublists.append(sublist)
        sublist_indices[tuple(sublist)] = [i, i]
    else:
        sublist_indices[tuple(sublist)][1] = i
```

For each sublist in `J1` you want to check if the sublist has already been recorded: if so, update the first/last indices as `[i,i]`, *else* (i.e. if it's already been recorded) just update the *last* index as `i`.

In Python, indentation really matters, so depending on previous language experience that might be unexpected. Also, in Python, a `for` loop can have an `else` of its own:

```py
for i in range(10):
   if i != 5:
      do_something()
   else:        # this else executes if the "if" statement condition is false
      do_something_else()
else:           # this else executes after the "for" loop is completed
   do_yet_another_thing()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(J1):
    d.setdefault(tuple(lst), [i, i])[1] = i
```

This is all you need, actually. You can create all your output straight from this `dict`:

```
len(d)
# 3
list(map(list, d))
# [[0, 3, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 7, 9, 10], [0, 0, 0, 9, 10]]
list(d.values())
# [[0, 2], [3, 4], [5, 5]]
```